# Maven+Spring+JavaFX проект без плагинов и требующих изменения структуры проекта библиотек

Tags: java, spring, javafx, maven

Когда я искал информацию о том, когда создать Maven + Spring + JavaFX проект, то постоянно сталкивался с такими проблемами:

1. Постоянно влезают в результаты поиска какие-то библиотеки, которые предлагают свою собственную архитектуру и конфигурацию проекта типа Spring Boot. Меня же интересуют JavaFX и Spring как отдельные библиотеки, не предполагающие масштабного изменения конфигурации и структуры уже имеющегося проекта.
2. Не нашёл ни одного примера с едиными способом определения maven-зависимостей. Вот например [статья на хабре](https://habr.com/post/348850/) об интеграции Maven, Spring, JavaFX. Отлично. Только где в [pom.xml](https://github.com/Symryvvin/SpringFXExample/blob/master/pom.xml) указана JavaFX среди зависимостей? А [в этом примере](https://devcolibri.com/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-javafx-2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8F-maven/) мы добавляем JavaFX в поле plugins. Это тоже незачёт: как-то раздражает, когда spring в dependencies, а javafx - в plugins.
3. В [Maven-репозиториях](https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=javafx) уйма JavaFX-библиотек, и какую использовать - не понятно. Естественно, что нас интересуют в первую очередь maven-зависимость от официального разработчика, т. е. Oracle, а библиотеки от третьих лиц нежелательны.

Вообще говоря, для ответа на данный вопрос достаточно добавить в приведённый ниже POM.xml определяющую основной функционал JavaFX зависимость в dependencies от официального разработчика данной технологии.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>JavaFX_Spring_Maven</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: JavaFX это уже готовое решение от разработчиков Java-ы и оно есть в JDK. Подключайте JDK и пользуйтесь. Понятие "Приложение Java JX" подразумевает что будет использоваться специальная структура: `Main.java`, `main.fxml` и `MainController.java` ну и конечно же код. Библиотеки расширяют базовый функционал JavaFX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

До JRE 9 JavaFX находился в jfxrt.jar, который был частью JRE. В JRE 7 этот jar нужно было добавлять в classpath. В JRE 8 этого делать уже не надо было, поскольку там jfxrt.jar помещён в директорию lib/ext в JRE. В JRE 9 JavaFX стал модулем, поставляемым с JRE и так же не требующим каких-то телодвижений для своей доступности. В выходящей в конце этого месяца Java 11 этот модуль уже не будет частью JRE и его придётся устанавливать отдельно. Очевидно, вы используете Java 8 или Java 10 и JavaFX доступен вам автоматически.

P.S. в ваш pom.xml я бы добавил параметры компиляции в соответствии с используемым вами JDK:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>10</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>10</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

или

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Так же я бы прописал в dependencies более новый Spring 5.0.9

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Поскольку я использую самые новые технологии, то буду ориентироваться на Java 11. Что Вы имеете ввиду под "отдельной установкой"? Появится новый Maven-репозиторий с JavaFX для Java11?

Comment: Тогда вам лучше дождаться выхода Java 11 и Spring 5.1 в конце сентября. JavaFX, разбитая на несколько модулей, будет доступна из центрального Maven репозитория https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx Сейчас там доступны предрелизные EA версии. С Java 10 они врядли будут корректно работать. Подождите, совсем немного осталось http://www.java-countdown.xyz/

Comment: Чтож, пожалуй сделаю как Вы сказали. Спасибо Вам за ответ!